# How to change the Java version in Google Colab?

Tags: java, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run pyspark on Google colab, which requires Java 8,  but when I look at the java version in Colab, it gives:

`openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode)`

I tried to change the Java version by using:

`!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"`

However, the java version still stays 11. This method worked back in July, when I used Colab then, but now also runs an error on that same notebook. 
I'm not sure if this is a new thing, but I can't seem to find anything to remedy this.

For reference, I was trying to use .count() on a spark dataframe, but kept getting

`IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you also need to update-alternatives:

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
!update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
!java -version
```

prints for me:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept the answer so that others don't spend time answering it only to realize it's already answered :)

Answer (score 1):

For Java 17 (not asked, I know), the instructions also need a small tweak, due to packaging differences:

```
!apt-get install openjdk-17-jre-headless -qq > /dev/null
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"
!update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
!java -version
```

which prints for me:

```
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+9-Ubuntu-122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```